# Which is the correct term, supervisor or coordinator?

Tags: postdocs

When someone is a postdoctoral researcher, is the person directly "above" him in the hierarchy called his supervisor, or his scientific coordinator?

Comment: It may be useful to add more context to this question. Is this for a CV, a letter to your parents, ...?

Comment: Also, the "tightness of supervision" among postdoctoral researchers varies significantly, so the "right" term will certainly depend on the specific hiring circumstances.

Comment: It is for a CV. The contract identifies him as the scientific coordinator, but I haven't seen this term before, so I was wondering which is more "formal"...

Comment: **Ask your supervisor/scientific coordinator/line manager/advisor/host/PI.**

Comment: In a couple of grants I have applied for, the paperwork used the term *(academic) host*. I like it: it implies a different relationship than advisor/advisee, in particular the fact that you can do your own research autonomously.

Comment: By the way, when in doubt I'd suggest using the official term from the grant, contract, or other formal documents.  If it sounds weird, then at least readers  of your CV may recognize that you are being formal.  By contrast, if you choose a term they aren't expecting and that's not the official name, then it can look much more like sloppiness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen the term "Line Manager" used in the context of post-doctoral researchers here in the UK.

I have also seen reference made in CVs to the principal investigator for the research project to which the author contributed, e.g. "I worked with Prof. X, Principal Investigator for Project Y". The term "Scientific Co-ordinator" seems to be most closely related to this.  Perhaps, therefore, the term "scientific co-ordinator" suits your purposes best.